# Django Migration - Migration missing some fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is an easy exercise, i'm a beginner about models and migration

> Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Flight(models.Model):
     origin = models.CharField(max_length=64),
     destination = models.CharField(max_length=64),
     duration = models.IntegerField()
```

Then i'm going on my prompt and type

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and in migrations/0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.7 on 2021-03-23 16:19

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Flight',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('duration', models.IntegerField()),
        ],
    ),
]
```

How u can see **origin** and **destination** don't migrate
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove ',' now try makemigrations

```
class Flight(models.Model):
     origin = models.CharField(max_length=64)
     destination = models.CharField(max_length=64)
     duration = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: I tried it. No mistakes, same migration. Also I tried to change the order in the model and it only "migrate" the last element

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: My pleasure Good luck :)